# new java.io.IOException : Call requires API level 9

Tags: java, android, api, exception, android-2.2-froyo

First, here is my code :

```java
public static boolean loginValide(final String username, final String password) throws IOException {
    final boolean valide = false;
    final String postData = "somePostParameters";
    URL url;
    HttpsURLConnection connexion;

    url = new URL("someUrl");
    connexion = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    try {
        connexion.setDoOutput(true);

        final DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(connexion.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(postData);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        final int responseCode = connexion.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IOException(e); /* I am retrowing an exception so the
        finally block is still called */
    }
    finally {
        connexion.disconnect(); // Close the connection
    }

    return valide;
}
```

My problem is that I was first only declaring my method throwing an **IOException**. But if it happens, I suppose the **HttpsUrlConnection** would not be disconnected.
So I thought catching the **Exception**, rethrowing it so when my method is called by another class I can handle a network/connection error and tell the user about it, and so the code will still run the finally block to close the connection.

First, am I right? Or is there another way to do this?
I don't care about the `try{} catch{}` inside the method, I just want to be sure that the connection and streams will always be closed, whether an exception is thrown or not.

The other problem is the `catch{}` block where I throw the exception. Eclipse tells me:

```
Call requires API level 9 (current min is 8): new java.io.IOException
```

Seriously, I can't throw an exception using an API level below 9? I hope it's a joke...

Comment: Code in the finally block will always be called, even if the code inside the try-block throws an exception.

Comment: @archer backticks are for inline code, not every reserved word. Stop using them too much. If there are code blocks put them as a code block.

Comment: why don't you `throw e` ?

Comment: also, the finally block is _always_ called

Comment: @njzk2 Perfect, I didn't know I could do that. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in a finally block will always be called, even if the code in the try-block throws an exception. As for the API level restriction - it's the specific `IOException(Throwable)` constructor that was added in API level 9.

Comment: I know finally bloc will always be called. What I meant is, if i don't put `try/catch` bloc but only indicate that the method can throw an exception, is there a way to ensure that the **HttpsUrlConnection** is closed ? Because in this case I don't have a `finally` block...

Comment: @miNde you can always use a try-finally-block - the catch block is optional.

Answer (score 4):

To use `IOEXception` with throwable you need `min API 9`.. check

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html#IOException(java.lang.Throwable)

Answer (score 2):

You can change MIN api level in eclipse

If you go into your Manifest file and set

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> <!--in your case -->
```

Then you will have changed your entire project from running 2.2.X as a minimum to 2.3.X

While you are still building your app, you can change the minimum API level at any time.

Comment: Api level 8 is 2.2.X and level 9 is 2.3.X. What does 1.5 and 1.6 have to do with my problem ?

Comment: Yes but I want my application to be able to run on 2.2.X phones. So it doesn't resolve my problem. That's why I am asking how to do.